# AWS Elasticsearch Kibana with Cognito - Missing role

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, elasticsearch-opendistro

Following this article to set up Cognito auth for AWS Elasticsearch.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/get-started-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service-use-amazon-cognito-for-kibana-access-control/

Getting an error:

Open Distro for Elasticsearch

Missing Role

No roles available for this user, please contact your system administrator.

Anybody knows why I could get it[image]?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have enabled [Fine-Grained Access Control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/fgac.html#fgac-kibana) with your Elasticsearch domain, one of the assumed roles from the Amazon Cognito identity pool must match the IAM role that you specified for the **Master User**. Considering you have at least two existing IAM roles, one for the **Master User** and one for more **limited users**, this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/fgac.html#fgac-walkthrough-iam) may help you.

Alternatively you can configure the master user role same as [Cognito Authenticated role ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-cognito-auth.html#es-cognito-auth-config-ac).

Comment: AWS is such a nightmare for beginners. If they didn't give me  a credit for my startup Id never use it!

Comment: I've missed the "must match" part. Thanks for pointing that out. Here you still helping with your comment after 3 years :)

Answer (score 15):

The crucial missing part was the below:

- navigate to the Elastisearch domain on your AWS Elasticsearch console page
- After this, click on the “Actions” button -> “Modify master user"
- Then select “Set IAM ARN as master user” and in the “IAM ARN” field, add the IAM role ARN “arn:aws:iam::<aws_account_id>:role/<My_cognito_auth_role_assigned_to_the_cognito_user_group”
- click Submit

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It took forever to get here. I followed your instructions to add arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/CognitoAccessForAmazonES and voila! It worked!

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me, as well. In my case, I had to add the limited role I created in this case - i.e.: `arn:aws:iam::##########10:role/IAMLimitedUserRole`. This wasn't very intuitive in the AWS docs I followed.

Comment: @h-bomb you mean you had to add both IAMLimitedUserRole and IAMMasterUserRole?

Comment: Yes, @dp119. But I only had an issue with the limited role because I didn’t realize I had to go back and add the limited role in the field and submit. After further research, though, I  discovered that instead of doing this last step, I could have just logged in to Kibana and add the limited role and map it to the AWS role ARN as a backend role.